# peer to peer secure communication: any available solutions?

Tags: security

I checked similar posts but I think the problem here maybe slightly different.

The problem is to provide secure communication between two peers (e.g., A and B) who may not have, how to say, "strong coupling" before (like A has its public key saved on B, that kind of thing).

The trust is based on a common signalling server who does the initial authentication (e.g., XMPP). Suppose A and B both login to that server. How would they proceed with secure and direct communication? I guess relevant keywords, using the XMPP example, would be XMPP secure socks5 (so far, this topic is uncovered in doc). Thank you for your suggestion on how I could start to implement, preferably using available library with less amount of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One protocol to look at is [Off the Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging), which has been used with XMPP in quite a few projects. The challenge you will have is how the users authenticate to each other, in a way that resists man-in-the-middle attacks. OTR uses Diffie-Hellman to exchange an AES key for bulk encryption and SHA256-HMAC. Users can then authenticate each other using a shared secret (like a passphrase), or compare public key fingerprints out of band.

I don't know if it counts as "strong coupling", but the other approach is to use certificates signed by a trusted 3rd party. If A has a certificate signed by you, and B has a certificate signed by you, then A and B can communicate securely without needing eachothers keys a priori.